# how do I fix this Codeigniter-4 login controller issue?

Tags: php, authentication, model, controller, codeigniter-4

I am trying to create a phone & password-based login in Codeigniter-4, I have created the form and this is my controller

```
  public function auth(){

    $model = new LoginModel();
    $user_phone = $this->request->getVar('user_phone');
    $password = $this->request->getVar('password');

    $result = $model->where("user_phone", "$user_phone");


if($result->numRows === 1){
    $user = $result->row_array();
    if($this->password->verify_hash($password, $user['password'])){
        unset($user['password']);

        return $user;

    } else {
       echo ('login');
    }
} else {
  echo ('login');
}
```

}

This is my Model

```
class LoginModel extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'users';

    protected $allowedFields = ['username', 'password', 'user_phone'];

}
```

This is my view

```
        <?php
        $req_c       = $member["username"];


        ?>


          <div class="app-body__item-content padded">

              <div class="panel-body"><?= $req_c ?></div>

             ?>

          </div>

       <?php endforeach; ?>
       <?php endif; ?>
```

But it is not returning the user details in the View

Comment: For starters, you have not shown where you call the view. So you will need to do that at the very least if you want any help.

Comment: You still have not shown where you call the view. Your View Code is incomplete, you are using foreach??? Where??? It's not in the view.

Answer (score 0):

i think because you using double quote in here it make your $user_phone variable as a string

```
 $result = $model->where("user_phone", "$user_phone");
```

it should be like this

```
 $result = $model->where("user_phone", $user_phone);
```

or this

```
 $result = $model->where(["user_phone"=> $user_phone]);
```